# Reverse LinkedList in java

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, reverse

I need to understand simple example

```
 LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.add("J");
        list.add("A");
        list.add("V");
        list.add("A");
```

I have simple LinkedList and need pass it to method reverse

```
public void reverse(LinkedList list) {

}
```

which will return reversed new list

and I do not need any ArraysUtils for reversing it

what is the short and practice way for having reversed output.

The same needed understand also for simple arrays.

Comment: Naively, the way I would do it is to create a temporary copy of the list, delete the contents of the parameter and then iterate over the temporary backwards and add it to the parameter list. EDIT: I assume you will return the list by modifying the input parameter to the method reverse. This is a side effect that I don't think many would use in Java though, that's a different discussion however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void reverse(LinkedList list) {
    //run till middle and swap start element with end element and so on
    for(int i = 0, mid = list.size()/2, j = list.size() - 1; i < mid; i++, j--)
        list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));//swap
}
```

Note: `List.set(..,..)` method returns the element previously at the specified position

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Collections class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Your list will be reversed after that operation.

Comment: I know, but i need without Collectons and utils:)) how reverse given list and array by hand?

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
public LinkedList<String> reverse(LinkedList list) {
LinkedList reverseList=null;

for(int i=list.size();i>0;i--)
{
reverseList.add(list.get(i))
}
return reverseList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

reverse method of Collections class is what you need i guess. You can change the implementation according to your need

```
/**
 * Reverses the order of the elements in the specified list.<p>
 *
 * This method runs in linear time.
 *
 * @param  list the list whose elements are to be reversed.
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the specified list or
 *         its list-iterator does not support the <tt>set</tt> operation.
 */
public static void reverse(List<?> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (size < REVERSE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
        for (int i=0, mid=size>>1, j=size-1; i<mid; i++, j--)
            swap(list, i, j);
    } else {
        ListIterator fwd = list.listIterator();
        ListIterator rev = list.listIterator(size);
        for (int i=0, mid=list.size()>>1; i<mid; i++) {
    Object tmp = fwd.next();
            fwd.set(rev.previous());
            rev.set(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
    if(head == null) return head;

    Stack<ListNode> stack = new Stack<ListNode>();
    while(head != null) {
        stack.push(head);
        head = head.next;
    }

    ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
    head = dummy;
    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
        ListNode current = stack.pop();
        head.next = new ListNode(current.val);
        head = head.next;
    }

    return dummy.next;
}
```